# Ratio and proportion: at what distance from the Earth will a spacecraft be equally attracted by the Earth and the Moon?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, physics, ratio

At what distance from the Earth will a spacecraft be equally attracted by the Earth and the Moon? The distance from the Earth to the Moon is approximately $385000km$, and the mass of the Earth is about $82$ that of the Moon. Gravitational attraction between two bodies varies directly as the product of their masses and inversely as the square of distance between them.

The answer is $347 000 km$ but I can't seem to set up the question correctly to get there.

Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried?  We can't tell you what you're doing wrong without seeing what you did.

Comment: I don't really know how to model this question.

Comment: Suppose the spacecraft, the Earth and the Moon are collinear.  If the spacecraft is $k$ km from the Earth, how far is it from the moon?  What is the ratio of the gravitational attraction to the Earth to the attraction to the Moon?  What value of $k$ makes this ratio $1$?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure to be honest. This question is lost on me.

Answer (score 3):

Match the gravitational forcesas follows,

$$G\frac{m_em}{d_e^2}= G\frac{m_mm}{(d-d_e)^2}$$

Solve to get the distance from the earth,

$$d_e=\frac{d}{\sqrt{\frac{m_m}{m_e}}+1}=\frac{385000 }{ \sqrt{ \frac1{82}}+1}=346712 km$$

Comment: I am having some difficulty re-arranging for de to get there myself but thank you for the solution.